# How can I view all my statistics about the badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

I am trying to obtain more badges on ELU. For example, to gain Archaeologist, to which I am intersted to, I need to edit 100 inactive posts but I am not keeping track of the number of posts I've edited.  How can I view all my statistics about the badges, such as how many more edits I need to do to gain A-badge. I'm not doing it for badges, but I can spend a bit more effort if I'm close to getting a badge.

Or is there no surprise more magical than gaining an unexpected badge?

Comment: You can see your progress for some badges: See [Badge progress reports](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports/) at meta.SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, badges are very much *meant* to [come as a nice surprise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/34440/135907):

> Some of the badges are supposed to be surprises, not World of Warcraft style level grinds based on numbers.
>
> I worry that if we provide too many metrics:
>
> - it becomes noise, like a bunch of inscrutable F-16 cockpit gauges -- how are all these numbers *useful* except for these specific badges?
> - the badge becomes the explicit goal instead of the desired behavior
> - the badges are no longer a pleasant surprise and reward but an expected "level up"

As someone who actually happens to have Archaelogist, I know it did come as a surprise to *me*. When I got it I wasn't even aware of its existence and had to look up what it even meant.

There are only so many posts on this site anyway. And only so many of them stay inactive for long. And 100 is a big number. If the system constantly reminded everyone of their progress towards the badge, everyone would be actively grinding for it, meaning that *no one* would get it for years to come because we'd be stepping on each other's toes. (Case in point: the review queues.)